# Is the Admin SDK a part of Google APIs?

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm looking at [this](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client) Google API nodejs client. I also looked at [this](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/) list of supported Google APIs, and I noticed that the [Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/) is not included in the list. I want to use the Directory API for managing Groups, but I'm wondering whether the Admin SDK is a part of Google APIs, or is it a different set of APIs overall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Admin SDK is indeed part of Google APIs. However, it's not clearly visible in the API Discovery service unless you switch to [All Versions](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/) API view. Then, you can find the directory_v1, reports_v1 and email_migration_v2 APIs and their respective methods.

I faced this same confusion a few months ago as well.

Answer (score 2):

Admin SDK is part of Google APIs.  However, Admin SDK refers to a suite of Google Domain APIs.  You will have to be a bit more specific with which API you are referring to (Directory API? Reports API?)

Comment: Directory API. I'd like to use it to create something that can manage groups. It's not listed in the API explorer, but there's [this](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/admin/directory_v1/) link that also a part of the api explorer.

Comment: Sometimes, not all APIs are listed in the api explorer.  I would recommend using the OAuth playground and just supply your own scope: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

However, the link you posted here is the API explorer for Directory API

Comment: Yup, did that on purpose :) Thanks for your help. I'll do try using the oauthplayground.